# Rejecting an edit which adds an answer into a closed question

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, closed-questions, rejection-reasons

A user, probably to be helpful, tried to add an answer to [a closed question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5588323/website-just-got-hacked-question) by editing it.

I rejected the edit, without analyzing the question nor the answer, on the principle that an answer isn't welcome on a closed question.

Was I right, or was I just acting like some kind of rigid ayatollah ?

Comment: You were right, mister ayatollah! :)

Comment: You were acting like a fascist monkey with guns in there hands.  Am proud of you, mah boy!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you were. Editing an answer directly into the body of the question is **never** acceptable.